# Is there a proper way to handle subscriptions on iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, nsdate, subscriptions

I want my app to have a subscription service and the way I see it is by keeping `timeIntervalSince1970` as an "until" date. But that is easily avoidable if the user changes system's current time. Is there any better way to track that in offline mode?

Comment: you mean in-app purchased subscriptions? or some custom "subscriptions"?

Comment: @luk2302 I mean, I have to implement them myself anyway, right?

Answer (score 0):

take a look at this [post1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4008503/ios-how-to-measure-passed-time-independent-of-clock-and-time-zone-changes), it explain how to measure passed time, independent of clock and time zone changes.

you also take a look at this [post2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17437725/detect-device-time-change-only-when-it-is-changed-manually), it explain how detect device time change only when it is changed manually

Let me know if this helps you :)

Comment: I went ahead and found this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1450737/what-is-mach-absolute-time-based-on-on-iphone) about `mach_absolute_time()`. It returns an `Int64` based on an amount of ticks processor've done since last reboot. I think user is even more likely to reboot his device (after battery dies) than change time in settings. Correct me if I'm wrong.